# Indefinite integral of $\tan(x)e^{(tanx)}$.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Indefinite integral of $$\int \tan (x) e^ {(\tan (x))} \, dx$$
I have tried using integration by parts but I couldn't integrate it.

Comment: Why do you think that this integral could be evaluated?

Comment: The result should be $$\frac{1}{2} e^{-i} \left(e^{2 i} \text{Ei}(\tan (x)-i)+\text{Ei}(\tan
   (x)+i)\right)$$

Comment: This question was given in my book.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how are we getting that result?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tan(x)=y$ making
$$I=\int \tan (x) e^ {\tan (x)} \, dx=\int \frac y{1+y^2} e^y \,dy=\int \frac y{(y+i)(y-i)} e^y \,dy$$

Now, partial fraction decomposition and some obvious changes of variable will take you to the definition of the exponential integral function.

$$I=\frac12 \left(\int\frac{e^y}{ y+i}dy+\int\frac{e^y}{ y-i}dy\right)$$

$$J=\int\frac{e^y}{ y+a}dy=e^{-a}\int\frac{e^{y+a}}{ y+a}dy=e^{-a}\int\frac{e^{t}}{ t}dt=e^{-a}\,\text{Ei}(t) $$ So,
$$I=\frac12 \left(e^i\, \text{Ei}(\tan (x)-i)+e^{-i}\,\text{Ei}(\tan (x)+i) \right)$$

Comment: Ok. I have done it. Thanks